# C and Java how to keep function definitions separate, rather than new OnClickHandler(){

Tags: java, android

I have a good background in C, and now I am writing code for android/java.
What I fail to understand that why function definition of a handler function is done inside another function. Code becomes so messy and hard to maintain and understand( from a C programmer POV).

So I have this code

```
    final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menuButton);
btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new 
            Button.OnClickListener()
    {...}
```

Is it possible to have a function
`myButtonClickListner() {}` defined in the class and `btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener((SomeCast)myButtonClickListner`

I think there has to be a way, But I am not able to find it..

Please comment.

Comment: you can make class that implements `Button.OnClickListener` in own compilation unit(file) then you can call `setOnClickListener(new newclass)` you can also made listener as a filed of outer class with type `Button.OnClickListener` like : `private Button.OnClickListener onclick = new Button.OnClickListener() {...};` and then use it `setOnClickListener(onclick);` ... your "messy" code is just implementing interface in-place aka anonymous classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind using

```
final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menuButton);
btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new 
            Button.OnClickListener()
    {...}
```

such coding style is that the object and its implementation stays together at one place.
in above code we have used anonymous innerclass.

If you are not comfortable with such implementation then there is also another way of doing this.

In your activity, implement onClickListener like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button btnOk;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //find id of your button
    btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);

    //Registering it for click listener
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnOk:

        System.out.println("OK button is clicked");

        break;

    case 2:
        //some other controls

        break; 

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: thanks all... I was getting irked with som much nesting in single function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two ways to do this:

1- Have the containing class implement the OnClickListener interface. For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    //...

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState){
        //...
        final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menuButton);
        btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
            //
            break;
        }
    }
```

2- The second method is the one described by Selvin in his comment: creating a separate class, which implements the OnClickListener interface, and instantiate it in your onCreate(). So, assuming that you have a myButtonListener class in its own myButtonListener.java file, you can simply do:

```
final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menuButton);
btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new myButtonListener);
```

Comment: For (1) What if I have 5 such buttons ? So Should I write a switch case in my OnClick ?

Comment: Yes, a switch is the way to go. Edited answer accordingly

Comment: thanks I will do this way only... there has to be a stop on this messy code function inside function .... and no ending

Answer (score 0):

Implement `View.OnClickListener` on your class and override its `onClick` method. That would make the code somewhat cleaner.

But first i recommend you to have proper knowledge of OOP and Java.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement the OnClickListener interface and override the onCLick method. And on your onCLick() method you just need to add a filter for the corresponding View.

```
public void onClick(View arg0){
     if(arg0 == myButton){
            //do stuff when myButton is click
      }else if(arg0 == myOtherButton){
           //do stuff when myOtherButton is click
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**-** What you have encountered is know as `Anonymous Inner Class`.

**Anonymous Inner Class:**

- It has **no** name.
- It must **implements or extends one and only one Interface or Class respectively.**

**-** This is just a way of coding where you keeping the functionality of that view or component attached visually.

**The another way you can do that is by doing the following:**

**-** Implement the specific Interface that has the call-back method.

```
public class MainActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

  private Button buttonClick;
  ....
  ....

  onCreate(Bundle saveInstance){

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main_view);


  buttonClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_click);

  buttonClick.setOnClickListener(this);

  ...
  ...

 }


       @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {


        case R.id.button_click:

             // -------- Do you function here

                break;

             }
        }

}
```

Comment: Ya but thats Bad programming IHMO. Code organization is butchered here

Comment: Thats just personal choice of code, i prefer to keep the component with the code attached, as its easy to locate... where as some feels that have all the functionality at one place is easy... so its completely style dependent...